# Show prices with tax but don't charge tax

Tags: payment-methods, tax

how can I show prices with tax but not charge it on checkout page?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be to create a customer group that can do tax-free purchases. You can assign specific tax-free tax-rules to a customer group and assign that group to customers.

Please note that customers do have to be logged in for this to work, and when they are: **all** products will be tax-free, not only in the checkout page.

So that might be half an answer, but perhaps it's good enough to get you started.

On another side note: prices and tax-calculation are so deeply woven into Magento and how it renders and calculates prices that what you are asking for non-logged in customers might be a tricky thing to setup. Perhaps you could explain a bit more about your use-case in your question about *why* you want a feature like this.